# Creating method dependency in java

Tags: java, publish-subscribe

I have two methods names as sendSData() and sendCData() in MyClass.

```
class MyClass
{

       public void sendSData()
        {
          // Receiving Response from database
        }

        public void sendCData()
        {
         // send C Data
        }

}
```

I'm calling these two method from main method

```
public static void main(String ... args)
{
    MyClass obj=new MyClass();
    obj.sendSData();
    obj.sendCData();
}
```

It is possible for me to send sendCData request after if and only if I  got success response from sendSData() method.

How can I achieve this in java?

sendData() publishing data to server
. if I get success response from server then it will be possible for me to send sendCData(). 
I'm usung pub/sub model. I'm not calling any web service or REST service. 
for receiving respose I have separate subscriber

Comment: What do these methods actually do? It sounds like `sendSData()` operates asynchronously. How so? We're going to need more specifics.

Comment: Why not add a static global boolean variable and stick it inside the sendCData() to true, then run an if statement that checks for the condition of it

Comment: You could modify the method to return a `boolean`, and do `if (obj.sendSData()) {obj.sendCData();}`. Of have them throw exceptions and use a `try ... catch`.

Comment: How is a success response signaled? `sendSData` should probably return something to indicate success or failure (e.g. a `boolean`), or perhaps throw an exception on failure. That way, you can test the result in the main method and respond accordingly.

Comment: sendData() publishing  data to server. if I get success response from server then it will be possible for me to send sendCData().  I'm usung pub/sub model. I'm not calling any web service or REST service. for receiving respose I have separate subscriber

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean sendSData() {
    // handle whether or not the function returns true or false
    return true;
}

public static void main(String ... args) {
    MyClass obj=new MyClass();

    if (obj.sendSData()) {
        obj.sendCData();
    } else {
        // obj.sendSData() did not successfully respond
    }
}
```

With the above code `obj.sendCData()` will only run if `sendSData()` returns true (successfully responded).

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly check if `sendSData` was successful.

You can encapsulate that check in a new method that after calls `sendCData` or even check in the beginning on `sendCData` and if it weren't successful do nothing

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
class MyClass
{

 public static boolean setFlag = false;

       public void sendSData()
        {
          // Receiving Response from database
             setFlag = true;
        }

        public void sendCData()
        {
            if(setFlag==true)
            {
         // send C Data
            }
        }

}
```

Introducing a boolean can help you call sendCData and function correctly by checking if setFlag is true.

Comment: Why create a whole new variable to accomplish this? It's pointless. Look at using return statements.

Comment: @Nicolas This is just one way of going about it. There are multiple ways to accomplish this.

Comment: You have instance methods but a class variable. What if there is more than one instance of this class being used concurrently from separate threads?

Comment: @DavidConrad, I understand that would lead to some trouble but the person asking this has never mentioned this to be multithreaded

Answer (score 0):

You can most likely solve this issue following that has been already recommended (using a simple boolean flag).  However, there might be another alternative.  I think you can take advantage of Inversion of Control (IoC).  Even if this is not the best alternative for your case, or even if it is overkill, I recommend you going through this tutorial if you can:  http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc.html.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception from 'sendSData' in case of failure will also do the trick, it will ensure that 'sendCData' is not called.